# javascript - random div on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, random, load

Hoping someone can help as I do not know much about JS

I have 3 divs

```
 <div id="content1">This is content 1 </div>
 <div id="content2">This is content 2 </div>
 <div id="content2">This is content 2 </div>
```

I require some JS that randomly loads one of those divs on page load and hide the other two

Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This question should help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20046687/show-random-div-on-every-page-load-for-fancybox-modal

Comment: Generate a random number. PIck the one generated, show it.

Comment: @Elizion This question is probably a duplicate of that one. Voting to close.

Answer (score 8):

You can select all `div` elements when the page loads, then pick a random one to keep and hide the rest.

```js
var elems = $("div");
if (elems.length) {
  var keep = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; ++i) {
    if (i !== keep) {
      $(elems[i]).hide();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content1">This is content 1  </div>
<div id="content2">This is content 2  </div>
<div id="content3">This is content 3  </div>
```